How to delay Button execution
In WPF,the button command trigger normal is immediately;but sometime we need Prevent False Triggering by Unintentionally pressed;So how to Press and hold the button with some time,such as 1s,or 500ms,then trigger the binding command.
I hope it will work like behavior,just in Xaml to config the The duration time of the button.
Thank you very much, BionicCode! Inspired by you, I change a litte then it work well:
    public class DelayButton : Button
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Delay Milliseconds
        /// </summary>
        public int DelayInMilliseconds
        {
            get => (int)GetValue(DelayInMillisecondsProperty);
            set => SetValue(DelayInMillisecondsProperty, value);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DelayInMillisecondsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
          nameof(DelayInMilliseconds),
          typeof(int),
          typeof(DelayButton),
          new PropertyMetadata(0));

        /// <summary>
        /// Delay Command
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand DelayCommand
        {
            get { return (ICommand)GetValue(DelayCommandProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DelayCommandProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DelayCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("DelayCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(DelayButton),
            new PropertyMetadata(null));

        /// <summary>
        /// cts
        /// </summary>
        private CancellationTokenSource? delayCancellationTokenSource;

        /// <summary>
        /// Trigger flag
        /// </summary>
        private bool isClickValid = false;


        /// <summary>
        /// Mouse Down Event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override async void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (DelayInMilliseconds <= 0)
            {
                //One press,one trigger
                this.isClickValid = true;

                //Execute DelayCommand
                DelayCommand?.Execute(this);

                return;
            }

            try
            {
                this.delayCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

                await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(this.DelayInMilliseconds), this.delayCancellationTokenSource.Token);

                //cheack mouse and not triggr
                if (e.LeftButton is MouseButtonState.Pressed && !this.isClickValid)
                {
                    //One press,one trigger
                    this.isClickValid = true;

                    //Execute DelayCommand
                    DelayCommand?.Execute(this);
                }
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                return;
            }
            finally
            {
                this.delayCancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
                this.delayCancellationTokenSource = null;
            }
        }
        
        /// <summary>
        /// Mouse Up Event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.isClickValid)
            {
                //time not enough
                this.delayCancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
            }
            else
            {
                //time enough,For Next
                this.isClickValid = false;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Mouse Leave Event
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.delayCancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
        }
    }


You can use Task.Delay and task cancellation to delay the button actions.
To actually debounce the button (interpret multiple clicks within a time span as a single click) you would have to remove the cancellation part and guard the event handlers against reentrancy (or use a timer that can only be started once during the debounce period). But from your question it appears you just want a simple delay.
From a UX point of view delaying a button click  significantly degrades the user experience. It's not the behavior the user would expect from a button. And it's not intuitive to figure out that you must keep the button pressed for an unknown amount of time to invoke the action. I would consider this a UI design smell.
If the button will invoke critical actions, you should consider showing a confirmation dialog ("Are you sure?"- "Ok" or "Cancel"). Then cancelling this dialog could restore the original values (or simply swallow the button action).
I think that this is far better flow (in terms of UX) than using a delayed button.
Buttons are click-and-forget. There are well-known exceptions, where holding the button (e.g. RepeatButton) would continuously increment an e.g. date value. Every other scenario a button must execute on click where the duration of the pressed state should be irrelevant.
The following example creates a custom DelayButton that supports all click modes (press, release, hover) as well as keyboard input (space and enter) and that delays the Button.Click event and the Button.Command invocation.
It also shows visual feedback to give the user a cue for how long he has to press the button (a bar will "charge" to fill the button and turns from red to green once the delay has elapsed and the action commenced:

<!-- Use DelayInMilliseconds="0" to use it as a normal button -->
<DelayButton DelayInMilliseconds="1000" />

public class DelayButton : Button
{
  public int DelayInMilliseconds
  {
    get => (int)GetValue(DelayInMillisecondsProperty);
    set => SetValue(DelayInMillisecondsProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty DelayInMillisecondsProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(DelayInMilliseconds),
    typeof(int),
    typeof(DelayButton),
    new PropertyMetadata(0, OnDelayInMillisecondsChanged));

  private static void OnDelayInMillisecondsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    => ((DelayButton)d).UpdateProgressAnimation();

  public SolidColorBrush ProgressBrush
  {
    get => (SolidColorBrush)GetValue(ProgressBrushProperty);
    set => SetValue(ProgressBrushProperty, value);
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty ProgressBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    nameof(ProgressBrush),
    typeof(SolidColorBrush),
    typeof(DelayButton),
    new PropertyMetadata(Brushes.DarkRed, OnProgressBrushChanged));

  private static void OnProgressBrushChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    => ((DelayButton)d).UpdateProgressAnimation();

  private CancellationTokenSource? delayCancellationTokenSource;
  private bool isClickValid;
  private bool isExecutingKeyAction;
  private bool isExecutingMouseAction;
  private int reentrancyCounter;
  private ProgressBar part_ProgressBar;
  private Storyboard progressStoryBoard;

  static DelayButton()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DelayButton), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DelayButton)));
  }

  public DelayButton()
  {
    this.ClickMode = ClickMode.Press;
    this.progressStoryBoard = new Storyboard()
    {
      FillBehavior = FillBehavior.HoldEnd,
    };
    UpdateProgressAnimation();
  }

  private void UpdateProgressAnimation()
  {
    if (this.progressStoryBoard.IsFrozen)
    {
      this.progressStoryBoard = this.progressStoryBoard.Clone();
    }

    var delayDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(this.DelayInMilliseconds);
    var progressAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 100, new Duration(delayDuration), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(progressAnimation, "PART_ProgressBar");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(progressAnimation, new PropertyPath(ProgressBar.ValueProperty));
    this.progressStoryBoard.Children.Add(progressAnimation);

    var colorAnimation = new ColorAnimation(this.ProgressBrush.Color, Colors.Green, new Duration(delayDuration), FillBehavior.HoldEnd);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(colorAnimation, "PART_ProgressBar");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(colorAnimation, new PropertyPath("(0).(1)", Control.ForegroundProperty, SolidColorBrush.ColorProperty));
    this.progressStoryBoard.Children.Add(colorAnimation);

    this.progressStoryBoard.Freeze();
  }

  public override void OnApplyTemplate()
  {
    base.OnApplyTemplate();
    this.part_ProgressBar = GetTemplateChild("PART_ProgressBar") as ProgressBar;
  }

  protected override async void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.isExecutingKeyAction || this.ClickMode is ClickMode.Hover)
    {
      return;
    }

    this.isExecutingMouseAction = true;
    _ = Focus();
    _ = Mouse.Capture(this);

    try
    {
      this.delayCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
      await DelayActionAsync(this.delayCancellationTokenSource.Token);
      base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    {
      return;
    }
    finally
    {
      this.delayCancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
      this.delayCancellationTokenSource = null;
    }
  }

  protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.isExecutingKeyAction || this.ClickMode is ClickMode.Hover)
    {
      return;
    }

    this.delayCancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
    StopProgressAnimation();

    if (this.ClickMode is ClickMode.Release)
    {
      if (!this.isClickValid)
      {
        _ = Mouse.Capture(null);
        this.isExecutingMouseAction = false;
        return;
      }
    }

    base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
    this.isClickValid = false;
    this.isExecutingMouseAction = false;
  }

  protected override async void OnMouseEnter(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.isExecutingKeyAction)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (this.ClickMode is ClickMode.Hover)
    {
      try
      {
        this.isExecutingMouseAction = true;
        this.delayCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await DelayActionAsync(this.delayCancellationTokenSource.Token);
      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException)
      {
        return;
      }
      finally
      {
        this.delayCancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
        this.delayCancellationTokenSource = null;
      }
    }

    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
  }

  protected override void OnMouseLeave(MouseEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.isExecutingKeyAction)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (this.ClickMode is ClickMode.Hover)
    {
      this.delayCancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
      StopProgressAnimation();
      this.isExecutingMouseAction = false;
    }

    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
  }

  protected override async void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.ClickMode is ClickMode.Hover)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (e.Key is Key.Enter or Key.Space)
    {
      if (this.isExecutingMouseAction || this.reentrancyCounter > 0)
      {
        return;
      }

      try
      {
        this.reentrancyCounter++;
        this.isExecutingKeyAction = true;
        this.delayCancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
        await DelayActionAsync(this.delayCancellationTokenSource.Token);

      }
      catch (OperationCanceledException)
      {
        return;
      }
      finally
      {
        this.delayCancellationTokenSource?.Dispose();
        this.delayCancellationTokenSource = null;
      }
    }

    base.OnKeyDown(e);
  }

  protected override void OnKeyUp(KeyEventArgs e)
  {
    if (this.ClickMode is ClickMode.Hover)
    {
      return;
    }

    if (e.Key is Key.Enter or Key.Space)
    {
      if (this.isExecutingMouseAction)
      {
        return;
      }

      this.delayCancellationTokenSource?.Cancel();
      StopProgressAnimation();
      this.reentrancyCounter--;

      if (this.ClickMode is ClickMode.Release)
      {
        if (!this.isClickValid)
        {
          this.isExecutingKeyAction = false;
          return;
        }
      }
    }

    base.OnKeyUp(e);
    this.isClickValid = false;
    this.isExecutingKeyAction = false;
  }

  private async Task DelayActionAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  {
    var delayDuration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(this.DelayInMilliseconds);
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    StartProgressAnimation();
    await Task.Delay(delayDuration, cancellationToken);
    this.isClickValid = true;
  }

  private void StartProgressAnimation()
  {
    if (this.part_ProgressBar is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    this.progressStoryBoard.Begin(this.part_ProgressBar, isControllable: true);
  }

  private void StopProgressAnimation()
  {
    if (this.part_ProgressBar is null)
    {
      return;
    }

    this.progressStoryBoard.Stop(this.part_ProgressBar);
    this.progressStoryBoard.Remove(this.part_ProgressBar);
  }
}

Generic.xaml
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1">

  <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Rectangle Margin="2"
                     StrokeDashArray="1 2"
                     Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
                     SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                     StrokeThickness="1" />
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
  
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background"
                   Color="#FFDDDDDD" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Border"
                   Color="#FF707070" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Background"
                   Color="#FFBEE6FD" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.MouseOver.Border"
                   Color="#FF3C7FB1" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background"
                   Color="#FFC4E5F6" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Border"
                   Color="#FF2C628B" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background"
                   Color="#FFF4F4F4" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Border"
                   Color="#FFADB2B5" />
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground"
                   Color="#FF838383" />

  <Style TargetType="local:DelayButton">
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle"
            Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}" />
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
            Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Border}" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground"
            Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness"
            Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
    <Setter Property="Padding"
            Value="1" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:DelayButton}">
          <Border x:Name="border"
                  Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                  BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                  BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
            <Grid>
              <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                Focusable="False"
                                HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
              <ProgressBar x:Name="PART_ProgressBar"
                           Opacity="0.5"
                           Value="0"
                           Background="Transparent"
                           Foreground="{TemplateBinding ProgressBrush}" />
            </Grid>
          </Border>
          <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted"
                     Value="true">
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                      TargetName="border"
                      Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                     Value="true">
              <Setter Property="Background"
                      TargetName="border"
                      Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Background}" />
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                      TargetName="border"
                      Value="{StaticResource Button.MouseOver.Border}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                     Value="true">
              <Setter Property="Background"
                      TargetName="border"
                      Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Background}" />
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                      TargetName="border"
                      Value="{StaticResource Button.Pressed.Border}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                     Value="false">
              <Setter Property="Background"
                      TargetName="border"
                      Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}" />
              <Setter Property="BorderBrush"
                      TargetName="border"
                      Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Border}" />
              <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                      TargetName="contentPresenter"
                      Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}" />
            </Trigger>
          </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>


Thank you , BionicCode.Your code is good,I test it has a little bug, such as I set DelayInMilliseconds="1000",  not only pressed with 1s and also release mouse button, then Trigger command. I wish just pressed with 1s then Trigger command.

I explain why I need a button with delay trigger command, because some buttons commands should be carefull to trigger,but dont need dailog(1st diaglog will hold on program or hidde some ui area,2nd dailog need person read more and clik more, if i tell person you just press with a little time with some special ui-style-button,haha)

"as I set DelayInMilliseconds="1000", not only pressed with 1s and also release mouse button, then Trigger command. I wish just pressed with 1s then Trigger command." -  I'm sorry, but I didn't understand you. Right now, I need to press the button for 1s then it executes the command (while still pressing). You don't have to release the button. This is how it is currently. Do mean you want to hold 1s and then release and then execute the command? You want to trigger on release? Then simply set Button.ClickMode to ClickMode.Release: <DelayButton ClickMode="Release" ... />.

<local:DelayButton Height="50" Margin="10" Content="Change Id 1000" DelayInMilliseconds="1000" Command="{Binding ChangeIdCommand}"/>   Your Code I test it if use command binding,have to release the button.

Ok, thanks. I will take a look. Please wait.

Ok. It was working properly (no bug). The point is that the Button.ClickMode is set to Release as default. When I was testing the code I set it explicitly to Pressed (I was testing all modes). I have now set the ClickMode to Pressed from the constructor, so there is no additional configuration for you to do. I have also added a progress animation that provides feedback for how long the user has to hold until the click is commenced.  Please copy the full new version and add the styles to the /Themes/.Generic.xaml file in your project. Please let me know if there are any issues.

@ZhuYajun For the sake of completeness, I have added keyboard support. Now executing the button using space or enter will also trigger the delay and animation. And don't forget to adjust the namespaces in the styles (Genric.xaml).

Thank you ,you add the styles in visual is vesy pleasant when use it.But has a few problem,if I press time is not enough,but the command still will trigger.If I use space keyboard, then you clik anywhere will trigger command. For convenience，we can change code in here:https://github.com/ZhuYajunFly/WpfApp2.git

Thanks for the valuable feedback and your time to create the repo. I have updated the answer to show the latest version of the DelayButton. If there are more bugs please let me know. If you are happy then also notify me so that we can delete this conversation. I have added more logic to control the flow and to isolate input paths. It should now work as expected.

To enable proper customization, I recommend creating a "/Themes" folder in your project root and adding a "Generic.xaml" file to it. Then merge the "DelayButton.xaml" file (resource dictionary) into the "Generic.xaml" dictionary.

Wonderful!Almost perfect，if add two delay buttons or more buttons,you will find only which press enough time it will get "Focus",then use space-key can triiger it,otherwise trigger the old press enough time button.You can quickly check it https://github.com/ZhuYajunFly/WpfApp2.git

I have updated the code. Please try again (added Focus() call and improved some details).

Amazing and Perfect! Thank you BionicCode, you creat it with genius touch (progress with delaytime)！I think more and more people will willing to use it. I suggest you submit this code into MaterialDesignInXamlToolkit and HandyControl，maybe help more people! Thank you again, BionicCode.
